# Writing unit testing for conference management class

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing

I try to use `unittest` for conference class, but I am not sure that I have considered all condition or more complex tests should be added?

**conference.py**

```
from datetime import timedelta, datetime


class Conference:

    def __init__(self):
        self.inputs ='input.txt'
        self.outputs = 'output.txt'
        self.talks = self.proposals_extract()
        self.Track = 1
        
    def proposals_extract(self):
        talks = {}
        f = open(self.inputs)
        try:
            while True:
                line = f.readline()
                duration = ''.join(filter(lambda i: i.isdigit(), line))
                if duration:
                    talks[line] = duration
                elif (not duration) and  line:
                    print('for proposal {} no duration has been detected'.format(line))
                    break
                if not line:
                    break         
        except FileNotFoundError as e:
                raise
        f.close()
        return talks
    
    def delete_content(self, pfile):
        pfile.seek(0)
        pfile.truncate()
        
    def format_time(self, hours):
         return (datetime.min + hours).strftime('%I:%M %p')
    
    def plan(self, start, end, Output):
        start = timedelta(hours=start)
        end = timedelta(hours=end)
        
        while start < end and self.talks:
            item = self.talks.popitem()
            duration = item[1]
            proposal = item[0]
            print(self.format_time(start), ' ', proposal)
            Output.write('{}  {} '.format(self.format_time(start), proposal))
            start += timedelta(minutes=int(duration))
        start = self.format_time(hours=start) 
        return start
                
    def print_plan(self):
        O = open('output.txt', 'a')
        self.delete_content(O)
        lunch = self.format_time(timedelta(hours=12))
        while (self.talks):
            print('Track {}\n'.format(self.Track))
            O.write('Track {}\n'.format(self.Track))
            end_morning_session = self.plan(9, 12, O)
            print('{}  {} '.format(lunch, ' Lunch\n'))
            O.write('{}  {} '.format(lunch, ' Lunch\n'))
            end_afternoon_session =self.plan(13, 17, O)
            print('{}  {}'.format(end_afternoon_session, 'Networking Event\n'))
            O.write('{}  {}'.format(end_afternoon_session, 'Networking Event\n'))
            self.Track += 1
        
        O.close()
                                
if __name__ == '__main__':
    P = Conference()
    P.print_plan()
```

**TestConference.py**

```
import unittest
import conference as c
from datetime import timedelta, datetime
import io
from unittest.mock import mock_open, patch
from mock_open.mocks import MockOpen, FileLikeMock
import os

try:
    # pylint: disable=no-name-in-module
    from unittest.mock import patch, call, NonCallableMock, DEFAULT
except ImportError:
    from mock import patch, call, NonCallableMock, DEFAULT


class TestConference(unittest.TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        print('setupClass')
        
    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        print('tearDownClass')
        
    def setUp(self):
        print('setUp')
        f = open('input.txt')
        self.lines={line.strip('') for line in f}
        f.close()
        
    def test_proposals_extract(self):
        """Check effects of reading from an empty file."""
        myclass_instace = c.Conference()
        handle = open(myclass_instace.inputs, 'r')
        self.assertFalse(handle.closed)
        self.assertEqual('input.txt', handle.name)
        self.assertEqual('r', handle.mode)
        self.assertEqual(0, handle.tell())
        text = handle.read()
        self.assertNotEqual(0, handle.tell())
        self.assertNotEqual('', text)
        handle.close()
        self.assertTrue(handle.closed)
        talks = myclass_instace.proposals_extract()
        self.assertEqual(len(self.lines), len(talks))
        
        """Check calls made when `open` is used as a context manager."""
        with open(myclass_instace.inputs, 'r') as handle:
            self.assertFalse(handle.closed)
            self.assertEqual(myclass_instace.inputs, handle.name)
            self.assertEqual('r', handle.mode)
            self.assertEqual(0, handle.tell())
                
    def test_format_time(self):
        myclass_instace = c.Conference()
        time = myclass_instace.format_time(timedelta(hours=9))
        self.assertEqual(time,'09:00 AM')
        
    def test_plan(self):
        O = open('output.txt', 'a') 
        myclass_instace = c.Conference()
        end_session = myclass_instace.plan(9, 10, O)
        self.assertEqual(end_session,'10:00 AM')
        end_session = myclass_instace.plan(16, 17, O)
        self.assertEqual(end_session,'05:00 PM')
        O.close()
        
    def test_print_plan(self):
        myclass_instace = c.Conference()
        myclass_instace.print_plan()
        self.assertTrue(os.path.isfile(myclass_instace.outputs))
        self.assertFalse(myclass_instace.talks)

            
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Parametric files

It would be trivially easy to have `Conference` accept filenames as parameters to its constructor, and will make this more usable.

### Variable names

`Track` should be lower-case. `O` is a poor choice of variable name for a list of reasons:

- It should be lowercase
- It looks the same as a zero
- Generally speaking, single-letter variable names are mystifying, and it's only by luck that I understand it to mean "output"

`P` should similarly be called `plan`.

### Context management

Avoid `open`ing `f` and `O` and `close`ing them separately; put this in a `with` instead. Delete your `FileNotFoundError` block; it does nothing useful.

### Line iteration

Replace

```
        while True:
            line = f.readline()
            if not line:
                break
```

with

```
for line in f:
```

### Unpacking

Try replacing

```
        duration = item[1]
        proposal = item[0]
```

with

```
proposal, duration = item
```

assuming that there are only two items in this sequence.

### Spelling

`instace` = `instance`.

### Tests

This entire block:

```
    myclass_instace = c.Conference()
    handle = open(myclass_instace.inputs, 'r')
    self.assertFalse(handle.closed)
    self.assertEqual('input.txt', handle.name)
    self.assertEqual('r', handle.mode)
    self.assertEqual(0, handle.tell())
    text = handle.read()
    self.assertNotEqual(0, handle.tell())
    self.assertNotEqual('', text)
    handle.close()
    self.assertTrue(handle.closed)

    """Check calls made when `open` is used as a context manager."""
    with open(myclass_instace.inputs, 'r') as handle:
        self.assertFalse(handle.closed)
        self.assertEqual(myclass_instace.inputs, handle.name)
        self.assertEqual('r', handle.mode)
        self.assertEqual(0, handle.tell())
```

is not useful and should be deleted. You're basically testing that file IO in Python works, and spoiler alert: it does. The only valuable part of this test is when you call `proposals_extract` and validate its return value against known-good data.